# Solr cloud: No registered leader was found after waiting for 4000ms

Tags: solr, apache-zookeeper, solrcloud

I have created 6 collections, each collection is having 3 shards and 2 replica( solr version 5.5.0). For a few days my setup was working fine. But after some days I am getting the following error:

> Error while trying to recover.
>   core=Collection1_shard3_replica2:org.apache.solr.common.SolrException:
>   No registered leader was found after waiting for 4000ms , collection:
>   Collection1 slice: shard3     at
>   org.apache.solr.common.cloud.ZkStateReader.getLeaderRetry(ZkStateReader.java:607)
>     at
>   org.apache.solr.common.cloud.ZkStateReader.getLeaderRetry(ZkStateReader.java:593)
>     at
>   org.apache.solr.cloud.RecoveryStrategy.doRecovery(RecoveryStrategy.java:308)
>     at
>   org.apache.solr.cloud.RecoveryStrategy.run(RecoveryStrategy.java:224)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)     at
>   org.apache.solr.common.util.ExecutorUtil$MDCAwareThreadPoolExecutor$1.run(ExecutorUtil.java:231)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

I tried to restart zookeeper and solr both, also increase heap memory to 10 GB. But still getting the issue.

Comment: Are you running in a (K)VM or bare metal?

Comment: And what are your specs? how many machines are you using and how many CPU's? Is your environment kerberized?

Comment: Any solution for this problem!!!

Comment: What are your zookeeper timeout settings?

Answer (score 2):

We are experiencing the same problem with a 3 node machine (6 cpu and 30gb memory per node). Below are the steps I tried to come to a solution.

What we already tried and did not work:

1. Stop solr processes and restart
2. Increase/decrease memory of the Solr JVM
3. Recreated collection, but this was only a temporary fix for a day or so
4. Solr GC tuning: 
   https://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrPerformanceProblems#GC_pause_problems

What fixed the problem of "No registered leader found":

1. Reduced the number of shards, basically we were oversharding. We reduced the number of shards from 6 to 3 shards and kept 3 replica's. This means that every node now has 3 shards.
2. However, since we were indexing 10.000s of messages per second. I was also wondering what our CPU was doing. So I monitored the cpu load and cpu IO. I found that the CPU's were working on their maximum all the time, causing a high IO wait, which I thought was causing the biggest trouble (see images below).

The replica's had a hard time to keep in sync, because of this high IO wait.
I reduced the workload (messages being send to solr), so that the indexes didn't grow as fast as before. This helped bringing everything back to normal. My Solr cluster is green now for a while, and didn't experience any "election problems". IO wait was reduced to below 25ms and cpu usage was around 70% instead of being almost 100% all the time.

Generally, it is very difficult to tackle such a problem. Since a Solr cluster may work fine for a few days (even seen months in other posts). Monitor IO wait or even traffic coming into your Solr nodes. If traffic spikes occur, (daily!) indices may grow too large. You may also add more nodes and split shards, which reduces the load on one machine. I choose to reduce the traffic to the Solr machines, since we use Solr as an audit store and do not need part of the audit logging.

[image: CPU load on one of the Solr Hosts]
[image]

Comment: This should either be posted as a comment on the original question or as a separate question. Also - be sure to test with an external zookeeper ensemble if you're not already using it.

Comment: I think my post is now answering the question correctly